# How safe $mysqli->real_escape_string for controlling one select query that accept user input

Tags: php, mysqli, xss, sql-injection

My PHP application has a query that takes a md5 hash as an input, from a user via GET method, then it applies `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` to it. After that it runs the SELECT statement.

How safe that function is? is it possible to SQL inject it or XSS it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is safe. If you dont feel safe, it only has characters and integers, you can easily test it is a md5 string (see example below). But again, **there is no need for all of that**.

An alternative would be [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). They're a bit more complex, but safe:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", 'a1b2c3'); // s stands for String, i would be Integer
$stmt->execute();
```

This is a very simplefied example, the url above the codeblock explains more. Keep in mind that prepared statement have a overhead! doing this for 1 excecution per query will slow things down.

---

**Small example to check if a string could be a md5 hash**:

```
function isMd5($string){
    /// md5 strings are 32chars* long. Simple test, do that first:
    if( strlen($string)!==32){ return false; }
    // It only has chars (A-F) and integers, if any other character->not md5
    elseif( preg_match("^[0-9a-f]", $string) ){        return false; }

    // No errors, return true:
    return true;
}
// *rawmode ha 16 chars, but when you work with that, you'll know
```

This is not a very usefull function, because it will not really secure a lot, this is just to show you how you can verify info. You read the documentation to see the results, and make checks to test if it matches possible results.

Comment: Checking from A-F is is also better as MD5 can contain only the following characters 0123456789ABCDEF

Comment: did you use such a function (like ismd5()) before?

Comment: would you use it in your own code, and if so - why?

Comment: I only added that function to show the TS how one could verify information. I removed the text explaining that in one of my edits, and was adding it back again. No, I would not use it, see the last sentence of my answer

Comment: Is that the reason for the downvote? Because I gave an answer to his question, and gave an alternative (prepared statement). The function is just a bit of extra info he might like, not my actual answer. Changed markup a bit to emphisize that a bit more

Comment: I was blinded! That input should be hard to be verified for safety. I just did now think about checking whether or not it's a md5 hash. Thank all !

Answer (score 1):

It's safe. But if you want to be more safe, than you can use prepared statements, which is the safest way to create queries with any equation, not just MD5: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

> ## TL;DR
>
> No, it isn't *always* safe.

**Safe use requires that you…**

1. **…only use it to escape SQL [string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html).**

   If you are using untrusted data for any other SQL token, you must protect against SQL injection in some other way.  Some trivial examples:

   - attempting to use for escaping some other literal, e.g. an integer:

     ```php
     # use as /script.php?id=0+OR+1
     $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
     $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $id")
     ```

     This will submit:

     ```sql
     SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 0 OR 1
     ```
   - attempting to use for escaping an object identifier, e.g. a column name:

     ```php
     # use as /script.php?col=id%60+%3D+0+OR+1+--+
     $col = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['col']);
     $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `$col` = 123")
     ```

     This will submit:

     ```sql
     SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 0 OR 1 -- ` = 123
     ```
   - attempting to use for escaping SQL:

     ```php
     # use as /script.php?orderby=OR+1
     $orderby = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['orderby']);
     $mysqli->query("SELECT * WHERE `id` = 0 $orderby")
     ```

     This will submit:

     ```sql
     SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 0 OR 1
     ```
2. **…correctly *quote* those escaped string literals.**

   There are two possible ways of doing this.  Either:

   - quote the escaped string literal with single-quote `'` characters; or
   - *explicitly* set an [SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html) that includes neither [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) nor [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) *and then* quote the escaped string literal with double-quote `"` characters.

   If you don't fully perform one of these two steps, you could still be vulnerable to SQL injection.  For example, if the server sets `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` by default and you don't explicitly change from that mode:

   ```php
   # use as /script.php?name=%22+OR+1+--+
   $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
   $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = "'.$name.'"');
   ```

   This will submit

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = "" OR 1 -- "
   ```
3. **…only use it after first setting [the encoding of your database connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html).**

   The *same* encoding must be used at *both* client and server ends of the connection: the best way to ensure this is to call [`mysqli::set_charset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php).  Using other methods could leave you vulnerable to encoding attacks:

   ```php
   # use as /script.php?name=%bf%27+OR+1+--+
   $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
   $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'gbk'");  // sets only on server, not on client
   $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` ='$name'");
   ```

   This will submit

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '縗' OR 1 -- '
   ```
4. **…don't use a [vulnerable](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8378) version of the `libmysqlclient` library.**

   Prior to that bugfix (in MySQL versions 4.1.20, 5.0.22, 5.1.11), `libmysqlclient` was vulnerable to the above encoding vulnerability *even if* the connection character encoding was properly set.

Answer (score -1):

For sql injection, it is safe - it prevents mysql operators to be used in value.

I myself would validate the string beforehand with php, to give user an feedback, that something went wrong, like so:

```
if( ! preg_match('/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/', $md5)) {
    // show error message
}
```

This also protects from XSS, because you can insert only alphanumberic string.

Without php check you have two main options:

A - strip all tags from user input:

```
$safe_input = strip_tags($user_input);
```

B - Use encoded html

```
$safe_input = htmlentites($user_input);
```

And to prevent UTF-7 XSS, then specify character set at the top of your code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

More on xss [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Not the downvoter, but `strip_tags()` and `htmlentities()` should be used when outputting data, not when storing it. Always save data as close as original as possible :) Also, you say "*Without php* check you have two main options", and then you name 2 php functions..?

Comment: And the same thing goes for the `header()` :)